# What is the pronunciation of "Whie Malreaux"?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, pronunciation

Whie Malreaux is a Star Wars character appearing in *Yoda: Dark Rendezvous* and, briefly, in a hologram in *Revenge of the Sith*.

I would like to find out how this character's name is supposed to be pronounced. Are there any official sources where either a pronunciation is given or the name is spoken?

Comment: Ive added the legends tag because I believe Dark Rendezvous is not Disney canon. If I’m wrong or you don’t want legends answers feel free to remove it.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - It's not canon

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The official audiobook for [Yoda: Dark Rendezvous](http://www.audioeditions.com/products/SW-Yoda-Dark-Rendezvous-Sean-Stewart-293633.aspx) (written by Sean Stewart and read by Jonathan Davis) has it pronounced as

> **[Wee - Mal-roh](https://vocaroo.com/i/s0fk0FgZ0AJP)**

Comment: The last name is pronounced as it would be using French rules: "eau" is pronounced /o/ and the final "x" is silent.

Comment: @Fatalize - Mais oui